# How can we convert a Pandas Core Series into separate and distinct columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, series

I am normalizing a JSON response, like this.

```
df = pd.json_normalize(response, record_path=['data'])
```

Now, if I run this: `print(type(df['locations']))`

I get this result: `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

So, `'df['locations']'` is comprised of this:

```
df['locations']
Out[246]: 
0      [{'time': '2023-01-01T06:49:49Z', 'latitude': ...
1      [{'time': '2023-01-01T01:03:35Z', 'latitude': ...
2      [{'time': '2023-01-01T02:30:45Z', 'latitude': ...
3      [{'time': '2023-01-01T06:38:42Z', 'latitude': ...
4      [{'time': '2023-01-01T01:02:19Z', 'latitude': ...
```

Now, if I try this: `df = pd.DataFrame([df['locations']])`

I get this result: `[1 rows x 196 columns]`

I tried to mess around with the string, like this...

```
df_final = df.iloc[1:100].to_string()
df_final = pd.DataFrame(df_final)
```

I got an error saying:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

How can I normalize df['locations'] into 196 separate and distinct columns? That seems to be the issue here.

Comment: You should be able to do that directly with `pd.json_normalize` by using the `meta_prefix` and `record_prefix` params

Comment: It's not working. I can't figure out why 200 columns are jammed into 1 column. I don't understand that.

Comment: It is hard to tell what the issue is without seeing some sample json data  for `response` but something like `pd.json_normalize(response['data'], ['locations'], ['id', 'name'])` should work where `id` and `name` are other keys that you want to keep that are on the same level as `locations` Or you can do `pd.json_normalize(response['data'], 'locations')` if you just want the `locations` data

Comment: It looks like this works: pd.json_normalize(response['data'], ['locations'], ['id', 'name'])
I didn't know what the 'keys' were. Where can I find out more about this? Can you recommend a link that describes how these things work? Thanks so much!!

Comment: Here is the [pandas.json_normalize documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Comment: Sometimes it's just a challenge to know the terminology. When you know what to do, everything becomes easier. Awesome!! Thanks again!!